# Chemical Equation Balance

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, chemistry

How do i fix this problem without using null space matrix?

$$4NH_3 + Cl_2 \rightarrow N_2 H_4 + 2NH_4Cl$$

Also before that, I need to learn how to find vectors. If someome show me it, it would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "fixing the problem" : that it is unbalanced in its present state ? But this is not the case ??? Thus your problem is to find other solutions ? Why don't you say that under this form ?

Comment: ammonia + chlorine = hydrazine + ammonium chloride?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can first imagine that each molecule has an unknown coefficient and use conservation of energy to write equations. 
For example, let's track the conservation of hydrogen atoms, and we see that
$$xNH_3 + yCl_2 \rightarrow zN_2H_4 + w NH_4Cl$$

implies that

$$3x = 4z + 4w.$$

You can take it from here to write the system and solve using the method of your choice.

Comment: "conservation of energy" ?